# Azure Deployment Issue with PackageReference

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I enabled integration with Bitbucket in my Azure AppService to Deploy my repo.

My project is a .NET C# WebApp, and in Csproj i'm using PackageReference.

But In MSBUILD on Azure is throwing this error:

> error MSB4066: The attribute "Version" in element 
>   is unrecognized.

This is a similar issue:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d158825-ddba-469e-93b1-fd9be0152f39/azure-function-project-wont-compile-with-tfs-build-agent-error-msb4066-the-attribute?forum=AzureFunctions